# Get the names of containers in Docker

Tags: docker

I named my containers in Docker, but now I forgot the names...

How can I list all of the used names?

`docker -ps` just gives me the running containers and `docker images` gives me all the images but no names.

I just want a list where I can see how I named the different containers when I created them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned by *@nwinkler*, you use `docker ps -a` to list all of your containers even stopped ones.

Now, you can also use **Format** in combination to `docker ps -a` as a convenient way to print only part of the information that is relevant to you.

For example you can list your container IDs with their associated names with:

```
$ docker ps -a --format "{{.ID}}: {{.Name}}"
caee09882462: peaceful_saha
```

You can also use the regular table format with the column titles:

```
$ docker ps -a --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}"

CONTAINER ID        NAMES
caee09882462        peaceful_saha
```

If you only want a list of all the used names:

```
$ docker ps -a --format "{{.Names}}"
peaceful_saha
```

Comment: Thanks! On `Docker version 18.09.6, build 481bc77156
`, with `docker ps -a --format "{{.ID}}: {{.Name}}"`, I get `Template parsing error....can't evaluate field Name in type...`. But, `docker ps -a --format "{{.ID}}: {{.Names}}"` worked great and gives the same output. Also, [`docker ps` docs (under the **Formatting** section)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) only list `.Names` as an acceptable placeholder for `--format`.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `docker ps -a` to show all running and stopped containers.

The container ID will be in the first column of the output, and the name will be in the last column.

Example:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS                    PORTS                                                     NAMES
6b74154d7133  wnameless/oracle-xe-11g  "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sbi"   9 months ago  Exited (0) 13 days ago    8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49160->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49161->1521/tcp  oracle_xe
```